# how to sync existing outlook calendar with SharePoint site 2013

Tags: sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-calendar

I want to sync my existing outlook calendar with SharePoint site 2013.So if i make any change or update event etc on my outlook calendar then its need to update Sharepoint site. Is it possible?

Note: I want outlook calendar need to sync to SharePoint site. Not SharePoint calendar need to sync outlook calendar.

In advance, Thanks for Advises!!

Answer (score 1):

We can sync Outlook calendar with SharePoint.

To share your Outlook calendar on your SharePoint site, first create a new calendar on SharePoint team site.

After you create the new calendar, click the "Calendar" tab in the Calendar tools, and then click the "Connect to Outlook" or "Sync to Outlook" icon.

Click "Yes" or "Allow," when prompted, to establish the connection. Select the Outlook folder and libraries to share on SharePoint, then click "Sync Now."

Your Outlook calendar is synchronized with the new SharePoint calendar, and is accessible to your team site members.

Or else you can try with Calendar Overlay concept.

Hope this helps to you.

Comment: Hi Nagababu, After establish the connection, there is no option to Select the Outlook folder and libraries to share on SharePoint, then click "Sync Now.". Have u tried to connect Outlook calendar on your SharePoint site? Could you please screenshot how to select the outlook folder. We are in confused about what folder to select and we cannot see any "Sync Now" option also.

Comment: Ok, you can try with Calendar Overlay. Create one SharePoint calendar and overlay with outlook calendar. In Calendar list settings choose calendar overlay option, here you can connect with outlook. I workout this with SP2010 not with 2013. So try it once may be it supports in SP2013 or not.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to sync a traditional Exchange-Calendar to SharePoint out-of-the-box.

As Nagababu already answered, you can connect a SharePoint Calendar to Outlook. This works without much configuration. You have two options: [Connect to Outlook and Sync to Outlook](https://synkventures.com/2017/02/13/connect-to-outlook-and-sync-to-outlook-in-sharepoint-task-list-sharepoint-sharepoint2013-we-werent-able-to-start-syncing-your-tasks-because-one-or-more-prerequisites-for-connection-to-exch/). You might want to disable the Farm Feature "Farm Level Exchange Tasks Sync" to make use of the traditional "Connect to Outlook".

Another possibility with SharePoint 2013 is to use a [SiteMailbox](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj552524.aspx). Creation of the SiteMailbox is also triggered within SharePoint. But the Mailbox is stored within Exchange and behaves much more like a Exchange-Mailbox. As described in the article, it requires some configuration effort to get SiteMailboxes up and running.